# Breaking Weekly/Monthly partition into Daily partition

Tags: database, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I am working on a large DB table with millions of data rows in which we already have a weekly partition created on a DATE column.

Right now due to the increase in the data volume we need to create a daily partition on the DATE column for said large table.

Is there any way where I can break the existing Weekly partition into a Daily partition without any issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add a tag for which RDBMS you're working with.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results.